# Details on HUGECLOB in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, toad, sqldatatypes

I have seen many tables in toad where the column data is coming as 'HUGECLOB'. Can someone explain me how to see such type of columns and before that what are the data type of those columns and how do we store the xml or sql text file inside that

Comment: There is no data type `hugeclob` in Oracle

Comment: The Oracle [Developer Guide for LOBs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADLOB/adlob_intro.htm#ADLOB001)

Answer (score 3):

In TOAD the value of a field returning (HUGHCLOB) can be viewed by double clicking the (HUGECLOB) value in the row.  This will open a grid popup editor with the full value of the field.

If you want to view the data via sql try:

```
SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(FIELD_NAME, LENGTH YOU WANT(EX: 4000), STARTING CHARACTER(Ex: 1)) FROM TABLE;
```

This will allow you to view the beginning characters up to the length you specify.

Comment: Hi, I am aware of that part but I am more concerned with how the data is stored and how infront when we query it comes as HUGECLOB. Can you please help on that?

Comment: Data for a CLOB is stored the same way a VARCHAR column would be stored.  You simply see (HUGECLOB) because Toad assumes since the max size is 4GB for the field, it will not be helpful to generate a preview for the normal output window.

Comment: If you want to enable clob previews, go to View > TOAD Options > Data Grids > Data > check the "Preview CLOB and LONG data" box.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to know basically is that I created table as create table t (x clob); then I inserted some characters of 60000 inside that column for one row.. but when I query it as select * from t it comes as the whole character itself instead of the word 'HUGECLOB'. how to get the word 'hugeclob' when I query it. Is there any condition in the script of the table.

Comment: Following @kfinity's solution in these comments is your "Preview CLOB and LONG data" box checked?  If so I would try to uncheck it and see if this produces the results you expect.